# Having trouble reading information from a file using Scanner class

Tags: java

I wrote this simple program to try to read information from a txt file in my computer's D drive`

```
package readDisk;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ReadDisk 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(Path.of("D:\\test.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    String TestText = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println(TestText);
    }
}
```

I am getting an error message upon compilation which goes

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method of(String) is undefined for the type Path

    at readDisk.ReadDisk.main(ReadDisk.java:9)
```

I am following a sample program found in the 11th Edition of Core Java Volume 1 and I've looked all over, trying to find where I've gone wrong to no avail. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Indeed, the `java.nio.file.Path` class doesn't have an `of(String)` method.

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names always start with lowercase, i.e. `TestText` should be `testText`.

Comment: Well, to which Java version do you compile? Note that the [method you're trying to use](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#of(java.lang.String,java.lang.String...)) is only available from Java 11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As opposed to what some commenters say, the method you're trying to use [does actually exist](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#of(java.lang.String,java.lang.String...)). The method in question takes a required first argument, and then a variable number of arguments, effectuated by the [varargs construct](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1), which means [zero or more](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.4) arguments.

But it is only available from Java 11 onwards. You need to check your Java version.

An alternative would be that you use scanner with another argument:

- `new Scanner(new File(D:/test.txt), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`; or
- `new Scanner(Paths.get(D:/test.txt), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`

The constructors throw a `FileNotFoundException` and an `IOException` respectively. Make sure you either handle it or propagate it to the caller.

---

<sup>*Note: A quick local test has shown me that this actually works for me. So if your code still throws a `FileNoteFoundException`, my guess is there is something otherwise wrong with the file or filename.*</sup>

Comment: I do have Java 11 so I do not know why it does not work. However, I tried the solutions you gave and got these errors: 
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The constructor Scanner(File, Charset) is undefined

 at readDisk.ReadDisk.main(ReadDisk.java:9)`

and 

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The constructor Scanner(Path, Charset) is undefined

 at readDisk.ReadDisk.main(ReadDisk.java:9)`

Could I have a problem with my Java installation?

Comment: @naynay That is most certainly true. How do you build your Java files? Also, could you try to invoke `java -version`?

Comment: I compile them in eclipse. My java runtime version is 1.8 and my JDK version is 11 (javac 11.0.2, the latest build) @MCEmperor

Comment: @naynay I think somewhere here lies the problem. I do not use Eclipse myself, so I cannot accurately provide a solution to the problem. However, make sure Eclipse runs with Java 11 instead of Java 8. Otherwise, of course, you can try the alternatives.

Comment: I've tried more things and I've made some discoveries. First of all, I had JRE1.8 installed a long time ago and when I installed Java 11 just recently, the computer refused to notice the new one, even after changing the Environment Variables. I managed to get it to use the Java 11 JRE in the end. However, even though you said that my code normally will work fine, I run into an IOException. I swapped out the argument in mine for your two different arguments and I have the same problem. Any help?

Comment: @naynay That depends on what exactly is the exception message. Could you show it? Also note that the underlying code eventually performs some system calls or use the Operating System's API, so at that point it is a difficulty with your system rather than a Java issue.

Comment: So, here is the code that brings up the IOException

`package readDisk;
 import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ReadDisk 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(Paths.get("D:/test.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    String TestText = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println(TestText);
    }
}`

error message is `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Unhandled exception type IOException

 at readDisk.ReadDisk.main(ReadDisk.java:9)
`

Comment: Both `Scanner` constructors throw an exception, and you need to handle it. Didn't Eclipse warn you about that?

Comment: It did, but the problem is I do not know how to handle these. I just got started in Java and I've looked all over on how to solve this IOExcepetion but I can't find a way.

Comment: @naynay Then I think that you need to study [this tutorial about exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html). You have two options: either catch the exception thrown from the `Scanner` constructor using the `try ... catch` construct, or propagate it to the caller, by declaring a `throws` clause to the method. The article provides enough to figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing your Scanner as below, you don't need Path for this :

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("D:\\test.txt") , StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: I tried this and ran into a FileNotFoundException  even though I can cleary see the test.txt file in the root of the D drive.

Comment: @naynay use `/` instead of `\\`

Comment: @naynay Check if you have hidden the extension name.

Comment: @CommonMan that did not change the FileNotFoundException error message.

Comment: @GenoChen I checked that already. File extensions are not hidden and that of the file I want to read is ".txt".

Answer (score 0):

The [`Path.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#of(java.net.URI)) method, added in JDK 11, requires a `URI` as parameter, not a `String`. For example,

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(Path.of(new URI("file:///D:/test.txt")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Or you can simply use [`new Scanner(File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.File)), as other answer said.

Comment: Well, you're referring to the wrong method. It should be the method [`Path.of(String, String...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#of(java.lang.String,java.lang.String...)).

Comment: @MCEmperor Yes, like Ruslan's answer said.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine [`Path::of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#of(java.lang.String,java.lang.String...)) method can take only one argument since the second one is vararg. Just make sure you are using java 11

Comment: But I am using java 11. Java 11.0.2 to be more precise